# SwitUI: How to use @FetchRequest in ObservableObject class

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, core-data, swiftui

I am making a simple app using Core Data. In this app user just write down the message and after pressing the button it shows below and saves it into Core Data. But I wanted to make it in ObservableObject class. I used FetchedRequest in it and tried to run the program but after pressing the button nothing is appearing below.

Here is my class:

```
class DataController: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var fruits: FetchedResults<Fruits>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    override init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("idk: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchFruits(text: String) {
        
        let fruit = Fruits(context: moc)
        fruit.name = text
        fruit.userid = currentUserId
        
        try? moc.save()
    }
}
```

Here is MainView:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @State var text = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Button {
                dataController.isLoggedIn = false
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
            }.padding(.bottom, 10)
            Text("Names")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            TextField("Add fruit here...", text: $text)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .cornerRadius(20)
            Button {
                dataController.fetchFruits(text: text)
            } label: {
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .fill(.pink)
                    Text("Add Fruit")
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }.frame(height: 50)
            
            List(dataController.fruits.filter({ item in
                item.userid?.description ?? "error" == dataController.currentUserId
            })){ fruit in
                Text(fruit.name ?? "error")
            }

        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: I don’t think you can use  @FetchRequest outside of a View so you would need a standard NSFetchRequest instead

Comment: Ok, I am not quite sure how to convert @FetchRequest info NSFetchRequest. Do you have any idea or link to a site that could help me

Comment: Google it, there should be plenty of articles and tutorials on how to use NSFetchRequest. Its something you need to know when working with Core Data.

Comment: Anything that conforms to [DynamicProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty) needs a `View` both `@FetchRequest` and `@Environment` will not get updates values reliably if inside a `class`

Comment: Thanks, but I still couldn't find any answer on the Internet.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Comment: Of course another option is to move the fetch request to the view, then you can use @FetchRequest.